# Counterclockwise polar chart with Mschart

Tags: c#, mschart

I´ve been attempting to get a polar plotting in a PolarChart using MSchart, and I need it to be shown in a counterclockwise direction, I´ve been looking for any property that would change the direction of the chart angles from clockwise to counterclockwise, but haven´t found anything. Is it possible to do so? If it is, how I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there´s no such feature in polar mscharts.I only found a workaround for this question. The way to do counterclockwise plotting is by reversing yourself all the labels(ex. 30 -> 330; 60->300; 90->270..etc)and your data also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible.
Reference http://support2.dundas.com/forum/tm.aspx?m=10418

Comment: that´s from 2008, what happened to the development of this project since then? has it been canceled?

Comment: I dont think this feature was added. May be Microsoft should work on this :)